Tkinter interpreting the long press of the button as many press and release events
I want to create a small virtual joystick with tkinter, so I need correct handling of long press of buttons.
I've created a code like this:
import tkinter as tk

def up():
    print("Up")
    up_button.config(image=up_active_image)

def reset_up(event):
    print("Up released")
    up_button.config(image=up_image)

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

up_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/up.png")
up_active_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/up_active.png")
up_button = tk.Label(frame, image=up_image)
up_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

root.bind('<Up>', lambda event: up())
root.bind('<KeyRelease-Up>', reset_up)

root.mainloop()


But when I press arrow-up for a long time I receive this output:
Up
Up release
Up
Up release
Up
Up release
Up
Up release
Up
Up release
...

While I'm expecting just one line with word up
What am I doing wrong? How to fix this problem?

@toyotaSupra how can it help me?

@toyotaSupra but it doesn't solve the problem, I need long press to be one long press, but in my case reset_up is called immediately after I press button

@toyotaSupra it's not a solution. I don't know how long user will hold button or how often he/she will press it. So setting timeouts is not an option

this might be useful

@DanyaK, can you make it as answer, because it helped me and I want to accept it as an answer. Thank you very much!

I really don't know which solution from that link actually helped you. You can probably post the answer here yourself and accept it.

@DanyaK, the first one (if you're interested). Anyway thank you very much once again!

A simplistic approach would be to use a variable to store a Boolean flag that gets set when Up is pressed, and reset when it's released. You can set the flag as soon as the button press event is detected, and use it to ignore subsequent firings of the event caused by key repeats while Up is being held.
import tkinter as tk

def up():
    if not upvar.get():  # if the flag isn't set yet
        upvar.set(True)  # set the flag
        up_button.config(image=up_active_image)
        print("Up")


def reset_up(event):
    upvar.set(False)  # reset the flag
    up_button.config(image=up_image)
    print("Up released")


root = tk.Tk()

upvar = tk.BooleanVar(root, False)  # set up a variable to store the button press flag

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

up_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/up.png")
up_active_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/up_active.png")
up_button = tk.Label(frame, image=up_image)
up_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

root.bind('<Up>', lambda event: up())
root.bind('<KeyRelease-Up>', reset_up)

root.mainloop()

Note that I've used a tk.BooleanVar instance to store the flag value, but you could also use a global variable
I also had to remove the image-related stuff to get this code to run, since I don't have those assets...but you get the idea.

This could work if I have multiple "press" events, but as I've written in my question I have multiple "press->release" events. So unfortunately it doesn't help.

How is it that you have multiple "release" events for a single "press" event? Unless I'm misunderstanding, they're mutually exclusive and should have a 1:1 relationship. If you're talking about separate events for different directions (left, up, right, down), you'll need separate Booleans for each (along with separate event bindings, but I imagine you're aware of that).

FWIW, in my testing of your code as-written (on Windows) I get multiple "press" events while holding down Up - i.e., "Up" is printed repeatedly (due to key repeats, presumably), followed by a single "release" event once I let go.

I've tested it on Ubuntu 22.04 and when I pressed up key once (for a few seconds) I had sequence of Up -> Up released events. But I want to get the same behavior as you've described in your last comment
